# Apps Script - Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end

Tags: google-apps-script

When I run a script  (**UPDATE_PRODUCT_DATA**) through the editor it runs fine. When it is run through a Trigger it fails.
It is failing at **getFilesByName** – but the file “**IJO 12.05.22.xlsm** “ is in my Drive.

**Execution Log:**
Info
IJO 12.05.22.xlsm
May 12, 2022, 10:05:54 PM
Error
Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. at 
convertExcel2Sheets(convertExcel2Sheets:3:60) at UPDATE_PRODUCT_DATA(UPDATE_PRODUCT_DATA:37:5)

**Part of UPDATE_PRODUCT_DATA that calls ConvertExcel2Sheets:**

```
//Get todays JO and convert it to Sheets & open it
joFile = SS2Name + " " + now + ".xlsm";  
Logger.log(joFile);
convertExcel2Sheets(joFile,SS2Name); //LINE 37 ERROR HERE
```

**ConvertExcel2Sheets script (LINE 3 highlighted):**

```
function convertExcel2Sheets(sourcefileName,convertedfileName){

  var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(sourcefileName).next(); //LINE 3 ERROR HERE
  var sourcefileId = sourceFile.getId();
  var sourcefileBlob = sourceFile.getBlob();
  var sourcefolderId = Drive.Files.get(sourcefileId).parents[0].id;
  
  var convertedfileType = MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS;
  var convertedFile = {title: convertedfileName, mimeType: convertedfileType, parents: [{id: sourcefolderId}]};
  Drive.Files.insert(convertedFile, sourcefileBlob, {convert: true});
    
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (it's not clear the data type / value of `SS2Name` and `now`, sometimes Logger.log doesn't provide enough details)

Comment: I'd guess that your function has a parameter and it's being filled with the triggers event object.  If that's not it then you must provide a [mcve]